# How can i rotate the particular view landscape or portrait programatically in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

how can rotate the particular view in Landscape or portrait mode in dynamically in android. i am using the this method

setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

but it total layout going to landscapmode .but i want particular view in landscape mode.
so,please tell me anyone known .Advance thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Following is code which i used to display your activity into landscape mode

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
android:name="yourActivty"/>
```

Change it according to your need